How to create custom JUnit5 annotation to add behavior
Is it possible to define a custom annotation in JUnit5 to execute some code before and after a test? It's not possible to add @Before and @After in my case as the before will use different values from test to test.
Maybe an example will be more explainatory. Instead of:
@Test
void myTest() throws Exception {
    try (AutoCloseable autoCloseable = TenantContextHolder.withTenant("one")) {
        // test something...
    }
}

Is it possible to define a annotation WithTenant that could be use like that :
@Test
@WithTenant("one")
void myTest() throws Exception {
    // test something...
}


I would suggest looking at the junit5 extension model and especially at intercepting invocations.

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-conditions

See https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-extensions which gives a nice tutorial on junit5 extensions

I achived my goal by doing the following:
First, by creating an annotation:
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Test
@ExtendWith(TenantExtension.class)
public @interface WithTenant {
    String value();
}

Then by defining an extention:
public class TenantExtension implements Extension, BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    static Map<Method, AutoCloseable> tenants = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) {
        Method testMethod = extensionContext.getRequiredTestMethod();
        WithTenant annotation = testMethod.getAnnotation(WithTenant.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            annotation = extensionContext.getRequiredTestClass().getAnnotation(WithTenant.class);
        }
        if (annotation != null) {
            String value = annotation.value();
            tenants.put(testMethod, TenantContextHolder.withTenant(value));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        AutoCloseable autoCloseable = tenants.remove(extensionContext.getRequiredTestMethod());
        if (autoCloseable != null) {
            autoCloseable.close();
        }
    }
}

As, I wanted the annotation to be at class level or at method level, I need to check if the annotation if present on the method first and then on the class.
The custom annotation contains the @ExtendWith junit 5 annotation in order to avoid developers to manually add it.
